# How can I identify which process caused my machine to freeze just before a manual hard-reboot?

Tags: windows, freeze, resource-usage

Over the past few weeks, my Windows 10 computer has occasionally ground to a halt without any explanation. Processes stop responding, the mouse cursor stops moving, and even the clock in the taskbar stops updating. I have to power-cycle my computer in order to continue what I was doing.

I assume that some process suddenly starts consuming excessive CPU or RAM, but I don't know for sure. I can only use information that was persisted to disk just before it starts happening. **How can I find out which process misbehaved after rebooting my machine?**

Some possibly relevant information:

- I'm using Windows 10 Pro, version 22H2.
- OS build 19045.3155, Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.19041.1000.0.
- Processor is an AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2950X 16-Core Processor, at 3.50 GHz.
- I have 128GB of RAM installed.

Comment: You need a RAM dump (and subsequent analysis) but if you are manually rebooting, a dump file is not being created.

Comment: Do I need a full dump, or would it suffice to just log resource usage for processes?

Comment: The dump would provide the best information. But there may be hints in the logs.

Comment: Why don't we just proceed with the logs? Like, how can I ensure they're enabled and of sufficient fidelity?

Comment: Whether the logs are still functional once a computer freezes is questionable. If the system isn't responding, why would logs still be responding. It is worth taking a look but I have never found logs to provide a smoking gun when a system goes haywire. Plus, there are inevitable warnings and errors that will pop up in the logs that have no meaningful impact on the system. So, they are worth looking at but they must be viewed in context of everything else that might be going on. With that said, go ahead a see if the logs reveal anything interesting - it can't hurt.

Comment: 128 GB of RAM could cause issues, in some cases. Have you set the page file size to stay the same (initial and max the same)? That *might* help... or not. Also use PerfMon.exe to log app usage.